# Take the center of an image

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that I need to tailor slightly.

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM photo p 
INNER JOIN room r ON r.id = p.room_id 
INNER JOIN project pro ON pro.id = r.project_id
```

I need to restrict this to only the first instance of p.id for r.project_id.

The idea is I only get the first photo id per project.

I also need it to select on the newest 4 projects.

How would I go about changing the query to get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(p.id),r.project_id
FROM photo p 
INNER JOIN room r ON r.id = p.room_id 
INNER JOIN project pro ON pro.id = r.project_id
GROUP BY r.project_id
ORDER BY r.project_id DESC LIMIT 4
```